# How to call a variable created adding a suffix to i within an R loop

Tags: r

Imagine I create this loop:

```
samples<-c('1sample', '2sample', '3sample')

for (i in samples){
vcf <- get(i)
nam<-paste(i, 'filtered', sep='_')
assign(nam, vcf)
}
```

Now, I cannot use `nam` because it was renamed with the sample name, I have tried some things like:

```
for (i in samples){
vcf <- get(i)
nam<-paste(i, 'filtered', sep='_')
assign(nam, vcf)
view(paste(i, 'filtered', sep='_'))
}
```

But this doesn't work. How can I call `i_filtered` variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can just use `get` as we already `assign`ed the 'i' named object to a new one with `_filtered` ('nam')

```
for (i in samples){
  vcf <- get(i)
   nam<-paste(i, 'filtered', sep='_')
   assign(nam, vcf)
   view(get(nam))

  }
```